# mysql replication: how to skip ahead

Tags: mysql, replication

I have mysql replication setup between a master and slave.Now it turns out that the slave fell behind. Any ideas how I can skip ahead the mysql replication if I care only about the most recent data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should catch up pretty quickly, but you can set the slave to start at any point. If you want to set it to where the master currently is, on the master run this command to discover where the Master is in the replication logs:

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

Then on the slave, use the CHANGE MASTER command to update the master log file and master log position to match what you see in the command above.

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='log_file', MASTER_LOG_POS=#;
START SLAVE;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/change-master-to.html

Alternatively, you can just skip ahead a certain number of instructions. But you usually only do that to skip over a problem.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-global-sql-slave-skip-counter.html